# ROS errors while exchanging messages with Stage

Tags: ros, simulation, messages, stage

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello everyone
I'm just trying to write a simple C++ client of Stage package. Just to make a test, i want to write a short code to receive some odometry data from /odom topic and print it onto screen:

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "nav_msgs/Odometry.h"
#include "geometry_msgs/Pose.h"
#include "geometry_msgs/Point.h"
/* #include "geometry_msgs/Point" */
void chatter (const nav_msgs::Odometry mes){
    geometry_msgs::Pose robot_pose = mes.pose;
    geometry_msgs::Point robot_point = robot_pose.position; 
    float xCoord = robot_point.x;
    float yCoord = robot_point.y;
    float zCoord = robot_point.z;
    ROS_INFO("I received %f %f %f/n", xCoord, yCoord, zCoord);  
}
int main(int argc, char **argv){
    ros::init(argc,argv, "listener");
    ros::NodeHandle n;
    ros::Subscriber sub = n.subscribe("/odom", 1000, chatter);
    ros::spin();
    return 0;
}
```

Sadly ROS compiler gives me an error:

```
/home/ubisum/fuerte_workspace/beginner/src/listener.cpp: In function ‘void chatter(nav_msgs::Odometry)’:
/home/ubisum/fuerte_workspace/beginner/src/listener.cpp:8:39: error: conversion from ‘const _pose_type {aka const geometry_msgs::PoseWithCovariance_ >}’ to non-scalar type ‘geometry_msgs::Pose’ requested
make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/listener.dir/src/listener.o] Errore 1
make[3]: uscita dalla directory "/home/ubisum/fuerte_workspace/beginner/build"
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/listener.dir/all] Errore 2
make[2]: uscita dalla directory "/home/ubisum/fuerte_workspace/beginner/build"
make[1]: *** [all] Errore 2
make[1]: uscita dalla directory "/home/ubisum/fuerte_workspace/beginner/build"
make: *** [all] Errore 2
```

Could you help me? I'm both a ROS and C++ newbie. Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/47809/ros-errors-while-exchanging-messages-with-stage/) by [ubisum](https://answers.ros.org/users/3549/ubisum/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2012-11-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) on 2012-11-08**:
Can you edit your question and add the exact error that you're getting?

**Comment by [ubisum](https://answers.ros.org/users/3549/ubisum/) on 2012-11-08**:
Done. And I corrected which is the error I got

**Comment by [ubisum](https://answers.ros.org/users/3549/ubisum/) on 2012-11-08**:
Sorry for disorder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Change

```
geometry_msgs::Pose robot_pose = mes.pose;
```

to

```
geometry_msgs::Pose robot_pose = mes.pose.pose;
```

Check the definition of nav_msg/Odometry carefully - mes.pose is PoseWithCovariance.

---

Originally posted by [mmedvede](https://answers.ros.org/users/1773/mmedvede/) with karma: 221 on 2012-11-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3